# PL/pgSQL How To Create Test Query To Test Function

Tags: postgresql

I create a function that returns TEXT, end  I'm trying to create a simple query to test this function.
the query while looks like this:

```
CREATE  TEMP TABLE function_test(actuel TEXT,expected TEXT,t_result TEXT);
/* the t_result should be'passed' if function(actuel) = expected */
INSERT INTO 
    function_test(actuel ,expected);
VALUES 
    ('a','A'),/*function(`a`) return 'A'*/
    ('b','B'),/*function(`b`) return 'B'*/
    ('c','C');/*function(`c`) return 'C'*/
IF function(actuel)=expected THEN 
    INSERT INTO 
    function_test(t_result) VALUES 'passed' ;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO 
    function_test(t_result) VALUES 'failed';
SELECT * FROM function_test;
DROP TABLE function_test;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QKak.png)
It would be nice if I could do it better than this.
thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but could you not just do either

```
select MY_FUNCTION('a','A') from dual;
```

or if you need a row on success and no row on failure

```
select 'PASS' from dual
where MY_FUNCTION('a','A') = 'YES'
```

DUAL is a 1 one row table that exists in every Oracle database.

Comment: thank you @McDonald for sending me back,
the man target is to insert 'passed' in t_result field
 if MY_FUNCTION(actual) value equals expected value, I can presume if the function runs correctly.

Comment: There is no `DUAL` table in Postgres. You can just leave out the `FROM` completely.